# Is it possible to add only certain parts of Gatsby.js to an existing HTML file?

Tags: html, reactjs, wordpress, gatsby

Say I have an existing html site, would it be possible to just import over the parts of Gatsby.js that would enable that file to communicate with a CMS like WordPress? Or is it absolutely neccessary that I have to recode this in React?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely possible, but whether or not it's worth doing is a completely different question. Gatsby is a React framework, so you would have to either change the mount point for Gatsby, which is currently `___gatsby` or your would have to create a div in your HTML with the ID of `___gatsby`.

If you look at the generated `index.html` in your `/gatsby-project/public` folder you'll see this div is present and empty, because like a React app, in the Gatsby version of `App.js` it's looking for that mount point.

However, if your use case is to just get data from a CMS, you'd probably be better off using vanilla JavaScript or PHP to pull from the endpoint. This is extremely dependent on what you need to accomplish.

### TL;DR:

You can do it, but maybe you shouldn't.

Comment: I was just largely curious to know if it could be done. Thanks allot for your help I'll read into this further.